# Octomap Navigation? How to?

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, ros-kinetic, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to use octomap for navigation?

After completing mapping process, i have a map in ".bt" or ".ot" format.  Now i want to do amcl on it (say gmapping). But gmapping requires ".pgm" map format. In this case how come i use the map from octomap to do the navigation. I am unable to understand how to acheive this by reading the documentation.

Can someone please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286337/octomap-navigation?-how-to?/) by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello RoboRos,

this is actually a very interesting question.
There exists a C++ library that could help you with your task. It is called [**grid_map**](http://wiki.ros.org/grid_map). As stated on the link provided, the grid_map is:

> *... a C++ library with ROS interface to manage two-dimensional grid maps with multiple data layers. It is designed for mobile robotic mapping to store data such as elevation, variance, color, friction coefficient, foothold quality, surface normal, traversability etc.*

Since using grid maps would be an entirely different topic, I will try to keep it short as possible by pointing out that there is a demonstration of an octomap conversion provided [here](https://github.com/ethz-asl/grid_map/blob/master/grid_map_demos/launch/octomap_to_gridmap_demo.launch). After installing the **grid_map** package, just change the path in the given launch file to point to your map - it will give you a quick demonstration of just what you could do with it.

However, I would advise you to play a bit with the package since the entire concept of grip maps is very interesting and above all, very useful.

If you have any further question, feel free to ask.

EDIT:
To save the image of the conversion, in *grid_map_demos/src/OctomapToGridmapDemo.cpp* add the following lines of code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include "grid_map_cv/grid_map_cv.hpp"
```

You need to include opencv in order to use `imwrite` and `grid_map_cv` is needed, because it offers the function for grid map to image conversion. Then, find this part (**it already exists**):

```
// Publish as grid map.
grid_map_msgs::GridMap gridMapMessage;
grid_map::GridMapRosConverter::toMessage(map_, gridMapMessage);
gridMapPublisher_.publish(gridMapMessage);
```

At that point, grid map is already constructed and you can save it by adding the following:

```
cv::Mat map_img;
grid_map::GridMapCvConverter::toImage<unsigned char,1>(map_, "elevation", CV_8UC1, map_img);
cv::imwrite("/home/<username>/octomap_occupancy.pgm", map_img);
```

You create a standard OpenCV Mat object, call the template function for grid map conversion with all the arguments and then just save the resulting image.
toImage function declaration is:

```
template<typename Type_, int NChannels_>
static bool toImage(const grid_map::GridMap& gridMap, const std::string& layer, const int encoding, cv::Mat& image)
```

---

Originally posted by [dljubic](https://answers.ros.org/users/32791/dljubic/) with karma: 516 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-03-27**:
Hi, Thanks for your response. This is really cool. However this is just downprojecting to a 2d map, right?

Not a full navigation solution.  I am not able to save it in some other format e.g .pgm. I mean, with this i am not able to publish map node. I can acquire map from projected_map:=map anywayz

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-03-27**:
however i'll have to say that i am stunned by the quality of the map outputted by gridmap.

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-03-28**:
@ddljubic any help would be appreciated....!!!!

**Comment by [dljubic](https://answers.ros.org/users/32791/dljubic/) on 2018-03-28**:
Sorry for the late response, I am quite busy these days.
I don't have time for the next few days to write and post a solution. In the meantime, you could take a look at the grid_map_cv folder, because grid maps provide us with the ability to transform between OpenCV formats and grid maps.

**Comment by [dljubic](https://answers.ros.org/users/32791/dljubic/) on 2018-04-01**:
@RoboRos I have edited my answer and added the code. Please let me know if it helps!

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-04-03**:
@dljubic Thank u for your response. Map has been saved in .pgm. Thanks alot for your help!!:)

**Comment by [dljubic](https://answers.ros.org/users/32791/dljubic/) on 2018-04-07**:
@RoboRos Sorry for the slow answering and I am glad to help! :)

**Comment by [h3ct0r](https://answers.ros.org/users/27010/h3ct0r/) on 2020-01-23**:
I didn't know about the grid_map package, very useful! thanks!